# Creating LDAP-Authenticated Login Sub-directory/DAM assets in CQ5

Tags: ldap, aem

I am running CQ 5.4 currently (5.5 upgrade pending) and need to establish a few sub-directories that can only be accessed by logging in and validating against the LDAP. This also means the files users can download after logging in have to be authenticated as well.

I have read as much of Adobe's documentation (and 3rd party) as I can:

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/howto/create_apply_cug.html

http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-4/deploying/dispatcher.html#/sessionmanagement

http://www.wemblog.com/2013/01/how-to-associate-cug-with-dam-asset-in.html

We have LDAP enabled to log in and use CQ5 on our development server, but this is different from having our publish server use it for subdirectory-specific authentication and allowing all other static pages be cached. Unless I'm reading all of this wrong, none points out how to accomplish such.

Having the default login component work with LDAP authentication would be wonderful, but I am not holding my breath.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to configure ACLs (access lists) for each node.

For example, through LDAP you export users which belong to group ldap-users. Then, if you go to Content Repository Explorer (/crx/explorer/index.jsp) -> Content Explorer - > Choose node you need to set ACL for -> Security Access Control Editor -> New ACE. There you can set the access rights for the node.

More on how to set the ACLs: http://helpx.adobe.com/cq/kb/CQ53ACLsMappingToCRX2.html